# Organizar informação em tabela

Tags: html

Estou a criar a seguinte tabela:

```
<div class="div1" id="employee_table">  
    <table class="table table-bordered">  
        <tr> 
            <th width="10%">De</th>
            <th width="10%">Assunto</th>
            <th width="10%">Prioridade</th>
            <th width="10%">Recebido</th>               
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <th width="10%" colspan=4>Recebido:</th>
        </tr>
                <?php  
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
        {  
        ?>  
        <tr>  
            <td><?php echo $row["De"]; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row["Conteudo"]; ?></td>  
            <td><?php echo $row["Prioridade"]; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $row["Hora"]; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row["Data"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <?php  
        }  
        ?> 
    </table>  
</div>
```

Mas a data não fica à frente da coluna `Recebido:` com `colspan =4`, como mostro na imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pretendia que aparecesse assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma seria eliminar a `td` da data e colocar a data após a string "Recebido:", colocando a `th` dentro do `while` e condicionando a impressão da `th` sempre que vier um nome diferente. É so colocar um `if` e atribuir o nome à uma variável, ficando assim:

```
<div class="div1" id="employee_table">  
   <table class="table table-bordered">  
      <tr> 
         <th width="10%">De</th>
         <th width="10%">Assunto</th>
         <th width="10%">Prioridade</th>
         <th width="10%">Recebido</th>               
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <?php
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
      {
         if($nomede != $row["De"]){
      ?>  
         <th width="10%" colspan=4>Recebido: <?php echo $row["Data"]; ?></th>
      <?php
            $nomede = $row["De"];
         }
      ?>
      </tr>
      <tr>  
         <td><?php echo $row["De"]; ?></td> 
         <td><?php echo $row["Conteudo"]; ?></td>  
         <td><?php echo $row["Prioridade"]; ?></td> 
         <td><?php echo $row["Hora"]; ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php  
      }  
      ?> 
   </table>  
</div>
```

O resultado será como abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Depois de analisar muito interessante a forma de retornar os dados desta forma. Vou optar por esta sugestão

Answer (score 2):

Acho que seu problema é com a organização das TH/TD

Pelo que entendi Recebido e Data tem que ficar dentro da mesma TR e a data com colspan 3 já que a primeira célula é o Recebido, veja

```css
td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1" id="employee_table">  
    <table class="table table-bordered">  
        <tr> 
            <th width="10%">De</th>
            <th width="10%">Assunto</th>
            <th width="10%">Prioridade</th>
            <th width="10%">Recebido</th>               
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th width="10%" >Recebido:</th>
            <th colspan="3">?php echo $row["Data"]; ?></th>
        </tr>

        <tr>  
            <td>?php echo $row["De"]; ?></td> 
            <td>?php echo $row["Conteudo"]; ?></td>  
            <td>?php echo $row["Prioridade"]; ?></td> 
            <td>?php echo $row["Hora"]; ?></td>
        </tr>

    </table>  
</div>
```